# Адаптировать div блоки

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Есть progress bar но как только я уменьшаю окно браузера сам бар уезжает вниз . Как его адаптировать ?

HTML

```
<div class="barra-progresso">
<div class="concluido">
<div class="percentual">
<div class="numero">0</div>
<div class="percent">%</div>
<div class="texto">заполнено</div>
</div>
  </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу еще стили, так как только одного html не достаточно

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="родитель d-flex">
   //content
   <div class="progress-bar">
      ///
   </div>
</div>
```

- Родителю добавьте ширину и позицию, если он не на всю ширину окна